# Relation between L1 and L2 norms for the Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

If Fourier transform of $f(y)$ is $g(\beta)$, then $|f|_{L_y^2}=|g|_{L_\beta^2}$ by Plancherel's theorem. Is there a way to compare $|f|_{L_y^1}$ to $|g|_{L_\beta^2}$ somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, if a function is in $L^1$, then the only thing one can say is that its Fourier transform is continuous and decaying at infinity, but not how fast it can decay.

- Example: take a smooth compactly supported function $0≤\varphi ≤ 1$ and define
  $$
  f(x) = \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|^{1-\varepsilon}}
  $$
  with $\varepsilon \in(0,1/2)$ so that $f∈ L^1$. Then
  $$
  \widehat{f}(x) = C_{\varepsilon}\,\widehat{\varphi} * \frac{1}{|x|^{\varepsilon}}
  $$
  is indeed continuous but only decays at infinity like $\frac{1}{|x|^{\varepsilon}}$ and so is not square integrable.

Similarly, if $f∈ L^2$, then $\widehat{f}$ is in $L^2$ but might not decay sufficiently at infinity to be in $L^1$ (take the same example but with $\varepsilon\in (1/2,1)$).